# Ansible show output of rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ansible

I've got the following ansible play:

```
- name: run rails tests
  hosts: marflar
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: vagrant
  tags:
    - rake
  tasks:
    - name: configure nokogiri
      command: bash -lc "bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries"

    - name: install gems
      command: bash -lc "bundle install"
      register: bundle_complete

    - name: check if database exists
      command: bash -lc "bundle exec rake db:version"
      ignore_errors: True
      register: rake_db_version_result

    - name: create database
      command: bash -lc "bundle exec rake db:setup"
      register: db_setup_complete
      when: rake_db_version_result|failed

    - name: apply database migrations
      command: bash -lc "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
      register: db_setup_complete
      when: rake_db_version_result|success

    - name: running the test suite
      command: bash -lc "bundle exec rake test"
      when: db_setup_complete
```

It works well, but I can't see the output of `bundle exec rake test` until after it has completed. Is there a way to show my test output as it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a [lot of people have requested this feature](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887), but that the Ansible maintainers have decided that this kind of feature [is not a good fit for the way Ansible is built](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887#issuecomment-54672569).

---

Edit for Clarity:

There are a lot of reasons that providing real-time output in ansible is not supported, there are a few solid arguments from the ticket:

> Ansible contains 235+ modules and the APIs used in basically all of
>   these modules don't have any capacity for reporting status in the
>   middle of an async operation

And

> The CLI has no good way to output standard out changes when running in parallel against several hundred hosts

If you really want to see the output of a command while its executing, you're probably better off trying ssh or some other tool, Ansible cannot do this.